# Barycenter and relative coordinates for schroedinger equation of the hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Heyho,

i just realized i am not sure how one gets from:

$\Big(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e} \Delta_{r_e} - \frac{\hbar^2}{2M_P} \Delta_{r_p} +V(r) \Big)\Psi(r_e,r_p) = E \Psi(r_e,r_p)$

to:

$\Big(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2(m_e+M_p)} \Delta_{_{R}} - \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} \Delta_{r} +V(r) \Big)\Psi(r,R) = E \Psi(r,R)$

with: $R=\frac{m_e \overrightarrow{r_e} + M_e \overrightarrow{r_p}}{m_e + M_p}$, $\mu = \frac{m_eM_p}{m_e+M_p}$.

(It is said to be a transformation into relative and barycenter coordinates.)
I would prefere an explanation in words first, why exactely are both forms the same?

If i express $r_e$ and $r_p$ in terms of the new coordinates i arrive at $r_e = R + \frac{M_p}{m_e+M_p} \overrightarrow{r}$ and $r_p = R - \frac{m_e}{m_e+M_p} \overrightarrow{r}$ but what then?
How do i replace the $\Delta$ operators? And especially, how do i get the term in the relative coordinates $\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} \Delta_{r}$ ?

Comment: This is the same canonical change of variable made in classical mechanics at the start of finding the form of general two-body orbits. The search term you want is "reduced mass". Then you just need to think about the properties of differentials to finish the job. As an pointless aside I had forgotten how much I hate the notation $\Delta$ for $\nabla^2$.

Comment: Expressions with the Laplacian in them are second order, but written with $\Delta$ they have the first blush appearance of being first order. While one can get used to that very quickly it offends the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get from

$\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m_e} \Delta_{r_e} + \frac{-\hbar^2}{2M_P} \Delta_{r_p} +V(r) \right)\Psi(\vec r_e,\vec r_p) = E \Psi(\vec r_e,\vec r_p)$

to:

$\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2(m_e+M_p)} \Delta_{_{R}} + \frac{-\hbar^2}{2\mu} \Delta_{r} +V(r) \right)\Psi(\vec r,\vec R) = E \Psi(\vec r,\vec R)$

with: $\vec R=\frac{m_e \overrightarrow{r_e} + M_e \overrightarrow{r_p}}{m_e + M_p}$, $\mu = \frac{m_eM_p}{m_e+M_p}$?

It can't be done, unless we say what $r$ is
But $\vec r_e = \vec R + \frac{M_p}{m_e+M_p} \vec{r}$ and $\vec r_p = \vec R - \frac{m_e}{m_e+M_p} \vec{r}$ we can figure out that $\vec r =\vec r_e-\vec r_p.$

> I would prefere an explanation in words first, why exactely are both forms the same?

As you noticed when someone gives you a $\vec R$ and a $\vec r$ then you actually know the $\vec r_e$ and the $\vec r_p$ too so you can compute $\Psi(\vec r_e, \vec r_p)$ so you can think of it as $\Psi(vec r, \vec R)$ or as $\Psi(\vec r_e, \vec r_p)$ and that notation is horrible but just think about getting the same complex number when you have the same configuration and you have the right idea.

Now you could ask what happens if you move a bit in the $\vec R$ direction which requires moving both particles the same way. Or you could trying moving a bit in the $\vec r$ direction which means moving the electron away from the proton. What you want is an expression about how those changes are similar to each other.

For instance if your complex number got 10% bigger when your $x_e$ changed 1% and your $x_e$ got when your $R$ changed 2% then changing your $R$ 2% can change your complex number 10%. The real point is that looking at how changes in your $\vec R$ and $\vec r$ change your function tells you what you your operator does. You want the same operator the exact same one just written in terms of changing different things.

The actual wave gives different values when you change configuration when you actual have electrons and protons at different configurations. Whatever coordinates you use it is the same function.

I myself would have written

$\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m_e} \Delta_{r_e} + \frac{-\hbar^2}{2M_P} \Delta_{r_p} +V(r) \right)\Psi(\vec r_e,\vec r_p) = E \Psi(\vec r_e,\vec r_p)$
and $\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2(m_e+M_p)} \Delta_{_{R}} + \frac{-\hbar^2}{2\mu} \Delta_{r} +V(r) \right)\Phi(\vec r,\vec R) = E \Phi(\vec r,\vec R)$
So that I can say $\Psi(\vec r_e,\vec r_p)=\Phi(\vec r_e-\vec r_p,(m_e\vec r_e+M_p\vec r_p)/(m_e+M_p)).$ Just to be less confusing.

Then you can just take you terms like $\partial/\partial x_e$ and apply it to $\Psi(\vec r_e,\vec r_p)=\Phi(\vec r_e-\vec r_p,(m_e\vec r_e+M_p\vec r_p)/(m_e+M_p))$ by using the chain rule on the function $\Phi.$ For all I know it was just confusing that they used the same symbol $\Psi$ for two different functions of six variables. The meaning is that it is one function of the 6d configuration. But having it spelled out can make taking the chain rule less confusing.

> If i express $r_e$ and $r_p$ in terms of the new coordinates i arrive at $r_e = R + \frac{M_p}{m_e+M_p} \overrightarrow{r}$ and $r_p = R - \frac{m_e}{m_e+M_p} \overrightarrow{r}$ but what then?

Those kinds of relationships are very helpful when using the using and doing the chain rule.

An example is to apply $\partial/\partial x_e$ to $\Psi(\vec r_e,\vec r_p)=\Phi(\vec r_e-\vec r_p,(m_e\vec r_e+M_p\vec r_p)/(m_e+M_p)).$

You get $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_e}\Psi(\vec r_e,\vec r_p)=\frac{ \partial}{\partial x_e}\Phi(\vec r_e-\vec r_p,(m_e\vec r_e+M_p\vec r_p)/(m_e+M_p)) $ which gives 
$\frac{\partial \Phi(\vec r, \vec R)}{\partial (x_e-x_p)}\frac{\partial (x_e-x_p)}{x_e}$+$
\frac{\partial \Phi(\vec r, \vec R)}{\partial (y_e-y_p)}\frac{\partial (y_e-y_p)}{x_e}$+$
\frac{\partial \Phi(\vec r, \vec R)}{\partial (z_e-z_p)}\frac{\partial (z_e-z_p)}{x_e}$+$\frac{\partial \Phi(\vec r, \vec R)}{\partial (m_ex_e+M_px_p)/(m_e+M_p)}\frac{\partial (m_ex_e+M_px_p)/(m_e+M_p)}{x_e}$+$\frac{\partial \Phi(\vec r, \vec R)}{\partial (m_ey_e+M_py_p)/(m_e+M_p)}\frac{\partial (m_ey_e+M_py_p)/(m_e+M_p)}{x_e}$+$\frac{\partial \Phi(\vec r, \vec R)}{\partial (m_ez_e+M_pz_p)/(m_e+M_p)}\frac{\partial (m_ez_e+M_pz_p)/(m_e+M_p)}{x_e}.$

In other words, by using the chain rule on the function $\Phi.$

If this is confusing consider a simpler problem. Let $c=a+b$ and $d=a-b$ and then consider the function $f(a,b)=g(a+b,a-b)$ where $g(c,d)=cd^2.$

Then $\frac{\partial g}{\partial c}=d^2$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial d}=2cd.$ So the chain rule says $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial c}\frac{\partial c}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial d}\frac{\partial d}{\partial a},$$ which equals $d^2(1)+2cd(1)$ and similarly $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=d^2(1)+2cd(-1)$ and we can check that since those give $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}= d^2(1)+2cd(1)=(a-b)^2+2(a+b)(a-b)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=d^2(1)+2cd(-1)=(a-b)^2-2(a+b)(a-b)$ and we know how to evaluate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}$ since $f(a,b)=g(a+b,a-b)$ and $g(c,d)=cd^2$ give $f(a,b)=g(a+b,a-b)=(a+b)(a-b)^2.$

> How do i replace the $\Delta$ operators?

Use the chain rule. The one from vector calculus with all the partial derivatives.

> And especially, how do i get the term in the relative coordinates $\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} \Delta_{r}$ ?

Use the chain rule, it will come out.

> Why do u consider the potential $V(r)$ only part of the relative movement term?

Many potentials on depend on how far apart things are. Newtonian gravity, electrostatic potentials, etc. So since they only depend on $|\vec r_e-\vec r_p|=|\vec r|=r$ and now you see why I always used the vector sign.

> And not of the barycenter movement term ?

It would be weird if things acted differently if all we didn't was shift all the things to a different place so depending on the location of the center of mass seems weird.

Comment: @Mareck I did an example of one derivative, evaluate the derivatives and then just do it again. Then do it for the other six directions then scale each one by the right thing and add them all up. It really is the chain rule you have $\Phi_n(\vec r,\vec R)$ and since $\vec r$ and $\vec R$ are functions of the electron and proton position you just do the chain rule.

Comment: @Mareck There aren't good shortcuts unless maybe you want to use matrices. Just take the derivative of $\Phi_n(\vec r,\vec R)$ with respect to $x_e,$ $y_e,$ $z_e,$ $x_p,$ $y_p,$ and $z_p$ and do them twice each and scale and then add the results. Doing random things and guessing is pointless when you already know the answer you should know why you do each step you do and it's just the chain rule for multivariate functions. Pull out a vector calculus book and start with a 2x2 if a 6x6 is just too big a jump.

Comment: @Mareck Did you check the edits I made to the answer in response to your comments? They are after the second block quote. I'm not sure you have any physics questions left ... it might be all math now.

Comment: @Mareck No you don't need the form of $\Phi_n(\vec r,\vec R)$ you are trying to act with $\partial x_e$ and having an answer in terms of partials for the other variables is exactly what you are aiming for. Never forget what you are aiming for.

Comment: @Mareck You are correct that $\partial (y_e-y_p)/\partial x_e=0$ and for second derivatives first take the complete first derivative with the sum of the products and then take the derivative again. The terms like $\partial (y_e-y_p)/\partial x_e$ all end up being scalars, and that just means you don't have to use the product rule when taking that second derivative if you do use the product rule on $\partial (h1)$ then you get $1\partial h+h\partial 1$ and then yes $\partial 1=0$ but again just do the actual chain rule step by step and it all works out.

Comment: @Mareck If you google schrodinger relative coordinates hydrogen atom then you can get some notes that might have more details.as for ignoring the center of mass. Each momentum eigenstate just cruises along at a fixed rate which is very boring and the whole thing is just a free particle which is studied in its own section so either already known so not new or will be talked about later so can be ignored now.

Comment: @Mareck The center of mass motion is relevant in Doppler broadening of spectral lines. So it helps things to happen even when the energies don't happen to line up absolutely 100% perfectly.